# S5 corded Desktop access

Tags: samsung, settings

I changed some settings on my S5 to reduce battery drain. Now I can't plug my charging cord into a PC or laptop and access the phone card or SD card. Can't figure out what to "turn" back on  ! Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

SO, I figured it out. Two things by the way - I discovered some usb cables are only good for charging a device, others will charge and do data transfer. When I plug my phone in, I get a notification about what to do with the unit, I click on the notification and I get options, the second option is **transfer data** problem solved